# ScrollBar issues on table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using a class which is extending View class. In this class I created table with 3 columns and added this table to scrollpane.Used

```
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {

            if ( getParent() instanceof JViewport ) {
                return ( ( (JViewport) getParent() ).getHeight() > getPreferredSize().height );
            }

            return false;
        }
    };
```

But I am getting Vertical Scrollbar when it is needed.But Horizontal scrollbar is not listing when 3rd column's contents very long.

Can anyone explain where the problem is?

Comment: check this link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682260/vertical-scroll-bar-in-jtable

Comment: Table column resizing and scroll bars don't play well together. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390324/jtable-which-is-scrollable-horizontally-and-grows-to-fill-parent-container

Comment: paste a code example that we can test

Comment: Why do you need the above code. The vertical scrollbar appears automatically with the default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try invoking [JTable#setAutoResizeMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode) as mentioned in tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width)